VisualStudio 2022 Templates: Difference between IWizard and IWizard2 interfaces
I use to create VS templates for fasten up my development.
I just notice that there is now an interface IWizard2.
Usually I use IWizard that is avalaible for VS2017, VS2019 and VS2022.
IWizard2 is only avaliable for VS2022.
It seems that the only difference is that Microsoft adds a new RunStarted method (the old one still exist) RunStarted(Object, Dictionary<String,String>, WizardRunKind, Object[], IVsProject, UInt32)
Did anyone knows the usage of the two added parameter IVsProject, UInt32.
Can it be used for adding project directly in the RunStart instead of waiting for the RunFinished method to add them?
It is a quite advanced question I think but could help.
Regards.
I did not try IWizard2 interface for now.
